# Error in running the AVD-Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

This is the first time I am working in AndriodStudio. At the first run of the AVD emulator the following error occures:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.

Output:

Could not bind or listen to socket: No error

RegGetValueW failed 2 The system cannot find the file specified.

libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

RenderServer::create failed to listen

RegGetValueW failed 2 The system cannot find the file specified.

Hax is enabled

Hax ram_size 0x15700000

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

qemu-system-i386.exe: it seems too many emulator instances are running on this machine. Aborting
```

so please help to solve this

Comment: `it seems too many emulator instances are running on this machine` How many emulator instances do you try to run at the same time?

Comment: Use actual device.

Comment: close all the running instances of emulator and start from first.

Comment: only one emulator are used for running.I deleted avd from .andriod but still same error appears -ManuToMatic